# "Translated a technical manual", does it serve the purpose?

Tags: word-usage

In the following sentence, I want to emphasize the idea that the translation was technical, that the user manual was related to technology, and not to any other fields or topics.

"He translated a technical manual."

Did I actually succeed in achieving my purpose?

Comment: I think it's fine grammatically, but I think you can directly mention the technology that the manual is for. I mean, something like "He translated [XX] motherboards manuals from English to ...." Btw, I am not a native.

Comment: OK. Thank you for your suggestion. Actually, I've thought of it too. I thought of writing "a cell phone user manual", but I'm not sure. Waiting for more opinions. Regards.

Answer (score 0):

"*He translated a technical manual.*"

This sounds enough okay. You can find many results of "technical manual" on Google. And I agree with Cardinal.

Comment: Ok enough? It's actually perfect.

Answer (score 0):

In some cases there is a distinction between user manuals and technical manuals. The term *user manual* may refer to a document that doesn’t focus on a thing’s technical **features**, but on its **benefits** to the user, while *technical manual* would provide more detail about how the thing works, how to repair it, and so forth.

Thus, a car’s user manual might address which buttons to push on the key fob to engage a particular function, while that car’s technical manual(s) might specify which IR frequencies the fob uses to exchange data with the car.